# CMake GUI with Ninja on macOS

Tags: cmake, ninja, cmake-gui

I'm trying to create Ninja build files using CMake GUI.

I've tried to install Ninja on macOS using Brew and manually. Both times I made sure that ninja is available on the PATH but CMake GUI was never able to find ninja.

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

CMake on command line is able to find ninja. Just cmake-GUI is not.

Any hints highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When apps are launched from the Finder (e.g. double-clicking on its icon), it is not necessarily the same `PATH` as launching from a command line. You can see the difference using a trivial CMakeLists.txt with the following contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
message("ENV{PATH} = $ENV{PATH}")
project(foo)
```

If you launch the CMake GUI app through the Finder and use the above file as the project to build, the output will probably show a path like this:

```
ENV{PATH} = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If you run CMake GUI from a command line directly (e.g. `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui` rather than `open /Applications/CMake.app`), the PATH should be the same as you are used to seeing from the command line, which for you probably includes `/usr/local/bin` assuming you've set that in your `~/.bash_profile` or similar.

Comment: WOW... seriously cmake ? like dah ? cmake was able to find ninja after running cmake-gui from terminal. But failed to find if run from CMake.app. Even though ninja was always in my env path. Ninja really likes to play hide and seek.