# CMake unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja"

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, build, qt-creator

I have MacOS Catalina, Cmake, Ninja and QtCreator installed with the following versions and paths:

```
[@bin]$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.15.6
[@bin]$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
[@bin]$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
[@bin]$ which ninja
/usr/local/bin/ninja
```

I'm trying to build a project with QT creator using Cmake. However, the following message appears in QT Creator

```
Running /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.2/bin/cmake '-GCodeBlocks - Ninja' -C /private/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/QtCreator-HXderc/qtc-cmake-TuClFWan/qtcsettings.cmake /Users/mymac/Documents/programming/Cpp/Qt/try6 in /private/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/QtCreator-HXderc/qtc-cmake-TuClFWan.
loading initial cache file /private/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/QtCreator-HXderc/qtc-cmake-TuClFWan/qtcsettings.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/private/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/QtCreator-HXderc/qtc-cmake-TuClFWan/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake process exited with exit code 1.
Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

As indicated on several websites (such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658014/ninja-not-found-by-cmake) I tried the following command but it didn't work:

```
[@bin]$ ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build
ln: /usr/bin/ninja-build: Operation not permitted
```

As indicated in the comments I tried also the following:

```
[@bin]$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build
Password:
ln: /usr/bin/ninja-build: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried:

```
[@bin]$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja-build
```

It didn't cause any error message but the problem in QT creator persisted

Comment: Did you try the command to create `/usr/bin/ninja-build` using `sudo`?

Comment: @AnthonySmith: many thanks for your comment, I just tried `sudo /usr/bin/ninja-build` (and edited the question accordingly) but it didn't work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, it should be `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build`.

Comment: @AnthonySmith:  Ok, I also tried `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build` but got an `Operation not permitted`

Comment: What about trying to put the symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` instead of the distrubution bin folder, that should still be in the path as well? `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja-build`

Comment: @AnthonySmith. So I typed `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja-build`. This I didn't get an error message, but the message in QT creator (after I restarted the computer) persisted

Comment: Are you launching QtCreator from the terminal, or from clicking on an icon? It seems (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220350/11357540) that they have different paths provided to them based on how they are launched

Comment: Also, it looks like the path for the `ln` command was wrong, looking at your `which ninja` return. Try `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja-build`, if that fails, try removing ninja-build `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ninja-build` and then try the command again.

Comment: @AnthonySmith: I launched Xcode (which I installted previously but didn't launch and it seems that there was some last setup at first launch that needed to be done) and create an alias for Qt Creator and launched it from terminal and it finally worked. So I don't know what was exatly the problem at the end... many thanks for your support!